# How to detect WP7 native resolution?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I realize there's only one resolution currently, but this would be nice to know. I'd also like to know how to set the orientation to portrait. I've managed to do it by setting the backbuffer size, but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Adam the chassis 2 spec (HVGA) was dropped before any devices meeting this spec were released. It is expected that Nokia will be releasing devices with a second screen resolution next year.

Comment: @Adam there are no WP7 devices which support a screen resolution other than WVGA. There are no official public details of any devices with other resolutions coming out. There are no recommendations on how to support other resolutions as to do so would require knowing what the other resolution(s) might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way it should be done:

```
ScreenWidth = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;

ScreenHeight = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```

You can set the default `Orientation` for the `PhoneApplicationPage` to `Portrait` with the `Orientation` property of the page, but you cannot force the `Orientation` change in any other way than rotating the device itself.